# Macro para update masivo en ACCESS

Tags: trigger, ms-access, asp, macros

como puedo hacer una macro para hacer update masivo, con una condición.
tengo esta Tabla de reservas. Cuando se hace una, se hace un insert en la tabla y el estado inicial es 0, todo esto lo trabajo en el html, despues con un boton hago que ese (o esos) estado (s) cambie (n) de 0 a 1.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

además de hacer un insert en otra tabla (detalle, donde ya vendría a ser una venta).
Lo que pasa es que como ahora es una venta, debería reducir el stock del producto vendido. Pero no sé como hacer eso de manera interna en el access, creo que sería con una macro, para que cuando se haga el cambio de estado de 0 a 1, desencadene la macro y se actualicen los registros.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creé esa macro, y en la tabla de reserva le puse que la ejecute despues de actualizar,pero no hizo nada, le pasé los parámetros que creí conveniente.. pero no resultó.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La macro la saqué de este video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-gKj36F5R80&t=157s en el minuto 17:30